# Python : Printing lists side by side

Tags: python

I am wondering how to print two lists of the same size next to each other.

I have got these lists from a nested dict.

Here are the lists:

```
[
  [
    "Chelsea", 
    "Liverpool", 
    "ManCity", 
    "Arsenal", 
    "Spurs", 
    "ManU", 
    "Southampton", 
    "West Bromwich", 
    "Everton", 
    "Bournemouth", 
    "Stoke", 
    "Watford", 
    "West Ham", 
    "Middlesbrough", 
    "Foxes", 
    "Burnley", 
    "Crystal", 
    "Sunderland", 
    "Swans", 
    "Hull"
  ], 
  [
    43, 
    37, 
    36, 
    34, 
    33, 
    30, 
    24, 
    23, 
    23, 
    21, 
    21, 
    21, 
    19, 
    18, 
    17, 
    17, 
    15, 
    14, 
    12, 
    12
  ]
]
```

Essentially, I want the list to be:

Chelsea: 44
Liverpool:37

etc...

Here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/League Standing', methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_league():
    text = request.form['league']
    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
    headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'key', 'X-Response-Control': 'minified'}
    connection.request('GET', '/v1/competitions/'+text+'/leagueTable', None, headers)
    response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
    teamnames = [r['team'] for r in response['standing']]
    points = [r['points'] for r in response['standing']]
    for teamname, point in zip(teamnames, points):
        print('{}: {}'.format(teamname, point))
```

I have tried formatting using %, but am not getting anything!

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) here as:

```
#               v  unpack content of list
for a, b in zip(*my_list):
    print '{}: {}'.format(a, b)
```

where `my_list` is the list mentioned in the question. In order to map these entries in the form of `dict` you have to type-cast the `zip`ed value to `dict` as:

```
dict(zip(*my_list))
```

which will return:

```
{'ManU': 30, 'Liverpool': 37, 'Burnley': 17, 'West Bromwich': 23, 'Middlesbrough': 18, 'Chelsea': 43, 'West Ham': 19, 'Hull': 12, 'Bournemouth': 21, 'Stoke': 21, 'Foxes': 17, 'Arsenal': 34, 'Southampton': 24, 'Watford': 21, 'Crystal': 15, 'Sunderland': 14, 'Everton': 23, 'Swans': 12, 'ManCity': 36, 'Spurs': 33}
```

Comment: wouldn't I need to still print out the jsonify version of this?

Comment: @f_harrison: Do you want to print the content or jsonify it?

Comment: @Moinundinn Quadri: Essentially, I would like to have the list in order of points with names and points. I do not necessarily think it matters if it is printed or returned. *my_list refers to my "response" variable, correct?

Comment: @f_harrison: Why doesn't it matter if it printed or returned? But if you think it doesn't matter, you have the solution :) Here `my_list` is the variable storing the `list` you mentioned in the question as  *Here are the lists:*

Comment: for teamnames, points in zip(teamnames, points):
        print('{}: {}'.format(teamnames, points))

is not working.

Comment: @f_harrison I doubt that I have written that in the solution

Comment: Right, you haven't. but     for t, p in zip(teamnames, points):
        print('{}: {}'.format(t, p))

also does not work!

Comment: @f_harrison: What value is your variable `teamnames ` and `points` holding?

Comment: teamnames = [r['team'] for r in response['standing']]
    points = [r['points'] for r in response['standing']]

Comment: Share the content you see on doing `print teamnames ` and `print points `

Comment: Please see my edits to the question, in which I give my python code