# Flask and Python return a zipped list

Tags: python, html, flask

This is insanely frustrating and I've been all over the interwebs trying to find this.

My issue is that I am not able to print my two lists - teamnames and points - next to each other.

When I print (see code) it prints correctly to the terminal output.

When I return the exact same thing, I am just getting the last place team!

```
@app.route('/League Standing', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def show_league():
        text = request.form['league']
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
        headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'key', 'X-Response-Control': 'minified'}
        connection.request('GET', '/v1/competitions/'+text+'/leagueTable', None, headers)
        response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
        teamnames = [r['team'] for r in response['standing']]
        points = [r['points'] for r in response['standing']]
        for t, p in zip(teamnames, points):
           print('{}: {}'.format(t,p))
        return jsonify('{}: {}'.format(t,p))




    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is what happens when I print to the terminal:

```
Chelsea: 43
Liverpool: 37
ManCity: 36
Arsenal: 34
Spurs: 33
ManU: 30
Southampton: 24
West Bromwich: 23
Everton: 23
Bournemouth: 21
Stoke: 21
Watford: 21
West Ham: 19
Middlesbrough: 18
Foxes: 17
Burnley: 17
Crystal: 15
Sunderland: 14
Swans: 12
Hull: 12
```

and when I print to the flask website:

```
Hull: 12
```

I want to return what is being printed to the terminal, the website!!!

Please let me know any ideas!

Please help.

Comment: Take another look at your code: You're returning only (t, p), which is the final value of your loop, not all of the element from the for loop.

Comment: Going back to my previous comment [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41268356/2063361). *There is difference between what you print and what you return via Flask*. All you need to do is `jsonify(dict(zip(teamnames, points)))`. And, this answer I had already mentioned in your previous post

Answer (score 0):

You are returning exactly what You see:

```
jsonify('{}: {}'.format(t,p))
```

This will create dictionary with only one item in it (with key `t` and value `p`, whose values are left over from previous `for` loop).

I suggest creating dictionary first by looping through zipped lists, and then sending that dict to `jsonify`. Something like:

```
return_dict = {}
for t, p in zip(teamnames, points):
    return_dict[t] = p
return jsonify(return_dict)
```